# Real numbers not working in Prolog

Tags: prolog, clpfd

I have following code:

```
:-use_module(library(clpfd)).
afn(A,B,C):-
    C #= B*A.
```

It works all right with integers but not with decimal numbers:

```
43 ?- afn(20, 10, C).
C = 200.

44 ?- afn(20, -10, C).
C = -200.

45 ?- afn(20, -10.5, C).
ERROR: Domain error: `clpfd_expression' expected, found `-10.5'
46 ?-
```

How can I work with decimals also here? Thanks.

Edit: I find following works with decimals:

```
afn(A,B,C):-
    C is B * A.

67 ?- afn(20.895, 40.5, C).
C = 846.2475.
```

Is 'is' a correct approach ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to distinguish

**Functional (or "moded") arithmetic**. This is the one you are familiar with from other programming languages: You know which of your arguments are input and which is output, and you simply compute the output from the inputs. That's what you get from **is/2** (which is part of standard Prolog), and if that's all you want to do, stick with it.

```
?- A=3, B=1.5, C is B * A.
C = 4.5

?- A=3, C=4.5, C is B * A.
instantiation fault                 <<< input B not kown
```

**Relational arithmetic**.  Here, you state an equation or inequation that must hold between the variables involved.  There is no notion of input/output arguments.  The system's job is instead to make sure that all the stated relations hold at the time a solution for the variables is presented.

There are many different ways to implement relational arithmetic, and many methods only work for subsets of the problem (e.g. only integers, or only linear expressions), therefore these features are typically provided in the form of libraries.

One available implementation of general relational arithmetic over the real numbers is [ECLiPSe](http://eclipseclp.org)'s [library(ic)](http://eclipseclp.org/doc/bips/lib/ic/index.html) (see [2](http://eclipseclp.org/doc/bips/lib/ic/index.html), [3](http://eclipseclp.org/doc/libman/libman.html)), which represents real numbers as floating point intervals:

```
?- A=3, C=4.5, C $= B * A.
B = 1.5__1.5                            <<< precise result

?- C $= B * A, C=1, A=10.
B = 0.099999999999999992__0.1           <<< imprecise but accurate result
There are 2 delayed goals.

?- ln(X) $>= sin(X).
X = X{0.36787944117144228 .. 1.0Inf}    <<< partially solved
There are 3 delayed goals.
```

Having said that, using interval arithmetic and interpreting results correctly is not always straightforward, that's why the kind of workarounds suggested by @mat can be useful (when applicable).

Comment: Thanks for a detailed answer.

Answer (score 3):

CLP(FD) implements reasoning over **integers**.

To extend declarative arithmetic to decimal numbers, you have basically two options:

1. use a dedicated constraint solver over *rationals*. See **CLP(Q)**.
2. scale all numbers so that only *integers* arise and continue using **CLP(FD)**.

I have seen both approaches successfully applied. Option (2) is sometimes preferable because CLP(FD) is more widely available, and also because you can successfully solve non-linear constraints with it over finite domains.

**EDIT**: In your case, a suitable query could look like:

```
?- afn(200, -105, C).
C = -21000.
```

At the end, you have to scale the results again. This way, you can simulate decimals via integers.

Note that resorting to *floats* is not a good solution at all, since you cannot really trust the results. Therefore, either use rational numbers or integers, as long as more advanced formats are not yet widely available in Prolog systems.

Comment: Can you give an example. It may be acceptable if decimal numbers are automatically rounded off to nearest integer. How can this be done.

Comment: You are using floats not decimals. `(is)/2` is very low level. Use constraints instead!

Comment: Can you give me some example of constraints here?

Comment: I checked here: http://net-informations.com/q/faq/float.html . I am interested in floats only since I do not need very high level of precision.

Comment: Still, why not simply benefit from high precision regardless? Use **rational** numbers or **integers** and suitable constraints.

Comment: You already have the code, as far as I can see. You only need to multiply the initial numbers by 100, 1000 or whatever you need to scale all of them to integers.